# Publish database between two open database connections (Visual Studio 2005)

Tags: sql-server, deployment, visual-studio

I have two data locations, one to a local and one to a remote database. How do I copy the local database schema to the remote?

The reason I don't use "Publish to provider" is that I'm not sure that I have all the information necessary to do so. I have the database name, server, username and pass but not "web service address" nor "web service password". I work in Visual Studio 2005. The server is a MSSQL 2005 server. I have tried using the queries but I only get errors doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing to provider does not mean that you publish the database directly from the local SQL server. What the tool does is generate a series of scripts that script out the scheme and inserts for the actual data. Since you have tried the queries and have gotten errors, you might want to focus on what those errors are and determine why you are getting those and once you find out why, you should then be able to run your scripts to move your database.

Hope this helps some.